# R: How to lazyload variables from inst/extdata in R package

Tags: r, lazy-loading, devtools

I have a file helper.RData file in my inst/extdata that contains
variables and datasets to be used by the functions in my package, 
but not meant to be accessed by the user.

I load it at the beginning of the package using:

```
load(system.file("extdata","helper.RData", package = "mypackage"))
```

As the file is big this takes quite a bit of time and it is especially annoying
during development (I use quite a loot the function `load_all()` from the `devtools` package).

I would rather prefer to have it lazy loaded so that the file is loaded only when actually needed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before being able to lazy-load your data you have to save your variables in a database that supports lazy load.

You can do this using the function `tools:::makeLazyLoadDB`  and later the function `lazyLoad`.

To create the lazy load database. Say you have the variables X and Y, the you have to create an environment that contains them:

```
e=new.env(parent=emptyenv())
e$X = X
e$Y = Y
```

next you create the database:

```
tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(e,"DBNAME")
```

of course you can change `DBNAME`.

You can the import it in R using `lazyLoad("DBNAME")`.

Comment: if there is any better way, I would like to hear it!

Comment: I discovered the function delayedAssign() which I think in many circumstances might be a good alternative to makeLazyLoadDB.