# How can I lazyLoad large model outputs that have been saved using saveRDS?

Tags: r, lazy-loading, file-handling

I have a few hundred large model outputs (8 Gb), each saved as a list containing many elements (and sub elements). To do further work on all these outputs it is not possible to load all 100 8 Gb files  at once into the environment and I came across `lazyLoad` as a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700619/get-specific-object-from-rdata-file), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583382/r-how-to-lazyload-variables-from-inst-extdata-in-r-package), and [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/lazy-load-with-archivist/). But have not succeeded in making the code work for me yet!

I suspect the problem might be coming from the data being saved using `saveRDS()` instead of `save()` (if I try `load()` a file saved with `saveRDS()` it gives an error) but I'm not certain.

I have two questions:

1) Is `lazyLoad` the correct way to deal with large outputs for indexing and loading individual levels of the data structure when called rather than storing everything in memory?

2) What am I doing wrong?

I have made several attempts along the lines of this:

```
e = local({readRDS("path/to/file.RData"); environment()})
tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(e, "path/to/file")
lazyLoad("path/to/file")
```

But the final line (`lazyLoad("path/to/file")` gives `NULL` as a result.

Since this is a general problem I haven't created a fake data structure as a reproducible example but can do so if required.

I thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1) `readRDS` requires assignment unlike `load`, so this works:

```
e = local({df <- readRDS("path/to/file.RData"); environment()})
tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(e, "path/to/file")
lazyLoad("path/to/file")
```

I should be saving my files according to convention using `.rds` as an extension when saving data using `saveRDS`.

2) Probably not the right approach in this case as indexing any element of the "promise" loads the whole file not just the indexed element.